# unable to clear flatpickr selected date on click of cross icon

Tags: reactjs, calendar, flatpickr

I am trying to use clear functionality which is available in flatpickr, but facing issue when i am using it in react-flatpickr.
My use case is very simple where I have added an svg cross icon and on click of that icon I want to clear the selected date in the flatpickr input field.

```
const element = document.querySelector("[class=flatpickr-input]")

<>
<img src={calendar} alt="calendar" className={'flat-calendar'} data-testid={'flat-calendar-icon'}/>
    <Flatpickr options={config} value={value && new Date(value)} onChange={(eventValue) => localOnChange(eventValue[0])}/>
<img src={crossFilled} alt="calendar" className={'clear-icon'} onClick={() => element.clear()}/>
<>
```

I am not sure if I am using it wrong or something I am missing, if anyone can help it would be great.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working using React refs. Created a reference of flatpickr using React refs and the called clear on the flatpickr ref.

```
const refComp = useRef(null);

const clearDate = () => {
  refComp.current.flatpickr.clear();
}

<>
<img src={calendar} alt="calendar" className={'flat-calendar'} data-testid={'flat-calendar-icon'}/>
    <Flatpickr options={config} value={value && new Date(value)} onChange={(eventValue) => localOnChange(eventValue[0])} ref={refComp}/>
<img src={crossFilled} alt="calendar" className={'clear-icon'} onClick={clearDate}/>
<>
```

Comment: Thanks for this post, I struggled for days with that madness...
I still wonder, there's probably a simpler solution. I tried to post an issue note on github but no one answered yet, i'll update if anyone does